# Speech-to-text conversion for Android App

Tags: speech-recognition, voice

Is there any low-computational-cost library framework to convert voice to text for an Android App (Java) without using web services or a server-side processing? What algorithms/paradigms can be used?

Comment: This is a programming question, therefore I moved it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This greatly depends on what speech you want to recognize, versus what you don't, and your desired error rate.

If you want to recognize only one word from a known user within otherwise silence at an accuracy rate slightly better than 50%, you might be able to develop or find some "low complexity" framework using audio level detection and/or sound fingerprinting.

For continuous speech recognition within a very large vocabulary from an unknown user of an unknown accent or dialect at a 99.9%+ accuracy rate, you might be unlikely to find anything, even with using server side processing.

For something in-between, you might want to take a look at using [CPU's Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) in an Android NDK build.  But I'm not sure whether or not someone would call the computational complexity of this "low" enough, nor the accuracy rate good enough for their purposes.

Comment: There is no need to be shy. Pocketsphinx is optimized for low computational complexity as well as the accuracy rate is quite good.

Comment: Pocketsphinx as an Android NDK build needs root access? Do you know any Android app in Google Play that uses this technology? Thanks